# Unable to open URL connection when deploying java code on unix box

Tags: java, unix

Below code opens a connection http://www.google.com :

```
try {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.connect();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                out.append(line);
            }

            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            LOGGER.info(urlName +" response time : " + (endTime - startTime) + " milliseconds");
            if ((endTime - startTime) > 30000) {
                LOGGER.info("********************************** Possible server lag *****************************************");
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
            System.out.println("MalformedURLException");
            System.out.println(mue.getMessage());
            mue.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("IOException");
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("url is "+urlName);
            System.out.println("Now exiting");

        }
```

This works as expected when I run locally on Windows but when I deploy it to a unix box I receive 401 exceptions. This indicates to me that the unix box is not sending some credentials that running from my local machine sends. I don't think this is a proxy issue as I am setting the proxy credentials before running of above code.

Is my analysis correct - this is a credentials issue ? If so how can I discover what extra details running locally is sending ? Is the jvm looking in a folder/file for these credentials, which does not exist on the unix box ?

Or do I need to inspect the traffic being sent as part of running the program using Wireshare or something similar ?

Comment: Post an error. And try `curl http://www.google.com` on that box.

Comment: @talex yes curl returns same error, thanks